Python: only length-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars error when trying to plot
I am new to python and am attempting to graph an equation using the following code.
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Data for plotting
L = 0.0001
b = 0.0079
h = 0.405
t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
y = 1/(b+(h*L))*[(h*L)+b*math.exp((-h+(b/L)*t))]
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

It returns TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when ran. Any help would be appreciated.

Which line number?

This is because you're trying to use math.exp() on a NumPy array (t). The math module functions like math.exp() are designed to work with single scalar values, not arrays.
Instead, you should use the equivalent function from NumPy (np.exp()), which can handle arrays.
Also, your equation has some bracket-related issues, you can't multiply an array by a list.
Here's the modified code.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for plotting
L = 0.0001
b = 0.0079
h = 0.405
t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)

# Corrected equation (using np.exp instead of math.exp)
y = 1 / (b + (h * L)) * ((h * L) + b * np.exp((-h + (b / L)) * t))

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

I hope this will help you a little.
